rviz2 is not able to create the rendering window Ubuntu 24.04
I've been trying to launch RVIZ2, but always I get the following error log:

QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
[INFO] [1722218336.755525763] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED  [INFO]
[1722218336.755651675] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5)
[ERROR] [1722218336.772153908] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error
creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid
parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at
./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp
(line 246)
[ERROR] [1722218336.772298763] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error
creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid
parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at
./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/
[ERROR] [1722218336.773535267] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error
creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid
parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at
./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp
(line 246)
[ERROR] [1722218336.773580461] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error
creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid
parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at
./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp
(line 246)
[ERROR] [1722218336.776422552] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error
creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Invalid
parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at
./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre_vendor-prefix/src/ogre_vendor/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp
(line 246)
[ERROR] [1722218336.776433805] [rviz2]: Unable to create the rendering
window after 100 tries terminate called after throwing an instance of
'std::runtime_error' what(): Unable to create the rendering window
after 100 tries
Aborted (core dumped)

I run glxgears and it runs at 60Hz as my monitor. I tried run rviz with software rendering with LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 and it didn't work. Also I uninstalled and installed rviz.
I used to be able to run rviz with ros foxxy and Noetic without problems.
Does anyone know what I could do to fix this?

try to run the following command before launching rviz2:
echo "export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
then retry rviz2, may succeed
